# Reset "Complete action using" choice

Tags: android, action, default

My application lists a bunch of hyperlinks which once clicked, open Complete action using dialog. I would like to implement a button which will reverse this choice if it has been made with Use by default for this action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *you* are the default, you can clear yourself via `clearPackagePreferredActivities()` on `PackageManager`. However, you cannot get rid of other applications as being the default this way.

If you want to force the user to make a choice from something you are launching from your own activity, use `createChooser()` on `Intent`.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it as soon as I get some time.